# git mv rename all files and folders to capitalize first letter

Tags: reactjs, git, github

I am renaming all my component names and folders. All of them start with a small letter. I am capitalizing them. The way I am currently doing is for the folder names I am writing

```
git mv folder test
git mv test Folder
```

as for the files directyl

```
git mv file File
```

I have a folder that contains around 50 folders and 200 sub-files. Can I automate this? I need to capitalize all them with git mv so that Github detects the changes. I use windows 10.

Comment: Do you have access to a usable shell?  I'm not really sure how one does any useful work in windows, but this is pretty trivial in a shell.

Comment: I have the powershell and git bash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course there are ways to automate it. Since you're apparently a JavaScript dev, you could look into the Node.js APIs;

- [`fs.readdir`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdir_path_options_callback) to read each name in a directory
- [`child_process.spawn`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options) to run `git mv ... ...`